# PHP-FPM timezone in the log files

Tags: linux, php-fpm

The PHP-FPM logs have different timezone. The time in the PHP-FPM logs is one hour behind the system time. Is there any option to configure time/zone in the PHP-FPM?

System: CentOS

```
# date
Mon Jul  9 17:33:10 BST 2012

# cat /etc/sysconfig/clock 
ZONE="Europe/London"

# grep "date.timezone =" /etc/php.ini 
date.timezone = Europe/London

# tail /var/log/php-fpm/error.log
[09-Jul-2012 16:21:58 UTC] PHP Notice: ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP currently only logs in UTC. This is a [bug](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=45191).

Comment: what you refer to as the bug, it was a) not PHP but syslog; b) it was standard behavior of syslog;

Comment: I don't think you are right. The php-fpm log is usually written directly by php-fpm and doesn't go through syslog first. Please read the bug I have linked.

Answer (score 0):

Issue could be related to a generic WordPress file of the name:

wp-includes/PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php

That file uses a miserable PHP function, of the name: gmdate()

That functions uses UTC…

I have replaced it with the echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); function (around line 928), and also placed directive: date_default_timezone_set('Myontinenet/MyCountry'); on the beginning of the file.

This seems to have solved the PHP error log, not logging current time, but UTC time.

I have found the problem by searching for the usage of the stringerror_log( on all my domain files. That is because this is the PHP function that logs error logs, and those wrong error log, came from somewhere….